# python subprocess question and letter b as result

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I try to query my hostname like

```
import subprocess
p2 = subprocess.check_output('hostname')
print(p2)
```

and the result is alway a letter **b** at the beginning.

*b'Nick-iMac.local\n'*

What could be the reason?

On my local Mac session I see:

```
$ hostname
Nick-iMac.local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `b` sigil indicates the type of the data; it's not part of the value. It shows that this is a `bytes` value, not a `str` value.

You want to use `universal_newlines=True` if your Python version is new enough (but then you'll probably also want to switch to `subprocess.run()`).

On older Python versions, `p2.decode('utf-8')` will return the value converted to a string; but then you need to know the correct encoding.

Going forward, this keyword parameter is called simply `text` since Python 3.7, though the alias `universal_newlines` will continue to work. It was always a bit of a misnomer, though; `text` is a better summary of all the small things it does.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188 for a somewhat more involved elaboration of some of these points.

Comment: It's not an error for a system to use a different encoding, but it's a bad smell - sort of like visiting a country where people are still allowed to smoke indoors willy-nilly. Open the windows and strive for https://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: By that logic, any use of Windows is a bad smell (not that some people wouldn't agree with that statement).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Indeed! Very astute observation.

Comment: @tripleee - thanks! I wonder how to store the result in a variable, like `p = subprocess.check_output('hostname', universal_newlines=True)` , but whenever I compare this one step later, it doesn't work as expected.

`if p == 'Nick-iMac.local':`

Comment: You still have the trailing newline.